How to deal with <script-setup> component imports and eslint rules like no-unused-vars
When using Vue
composition API with <script setup>, components are just imported like
import Component from '@/components/Component.vue';
How do I keep eslint from applying the no-unused-var rule here, without disabling the rule completely? I would like it to detect "real" unused variables but those imports are in fact used in the template section.

What is your eslint config? You should use plugins for any specific functionality, e.g. vue/script-setup-uses-vars in this case

If the imported component is actually used, there will be no warning in eslint

Did you find any solution? I am having this problem where eslint doesn't detect that the variables are used in the externally referenced template .html file.
